# query with CONTAINS on table without full text index

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

Without using dynamic SQL, and other than an `If` `ELSE` is there any way to test if a table has a full text index without causing additional locking.

I'm looking for some way that I can still execute:

```
SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE <not has full text index> OR (<has full text index> AND CONTAINS(*, 'fast'))
```

There is no full-text index on this the table `Cars` ideally I would like for it to just return all rows when we try and specify the contains string.

What I have currently from SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM Cars
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = object_id('Cars') AND COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id, name, 'IsFulltextIndexed') = 1)
OR (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = object_id('Cars') AND COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id, name, 'IsFulltextIndexed') = 1)
AND CONTAINS(*, 'fast'))
```

Which parses fine but fails because:

> Msg 7601, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT
>   predicate on table or indexed view 'Cars' because it is not full-text
>   indexed.

Is there a way to do this without dynamic SQL and without using an `IF` `ELSE`?

Bonus points if you can explain why the optimizer doesn't short-circuit the 1=0 and CONTAINS from `SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE 1=1 OR (1=0 AND CONTAINS(*, 'fast'))`.

In practice I will likely create a new class attribute and then use that to ignore the full text indexes in my ORM, but I am interested to see if there is another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

All single queries are compiled into a single plan, and so all the individual components must always be valid.  It is not possible to write a single statement where different components are valid in different circumstances.

To do so require more traditional programatic constructs.  These are available in T-SQL, but not within a single SQL statement.  As such, the solutions you have listed as innapropriate are actually the ways to resolve such issues.

Comment: On why the optimiser doesn't short-circuit your condition, the simple answer is that SQL Server doesn't ever short-circuit when building execution plans.  It may not evaluate certain conditions on execution (though it's behaviour is still different to short-circuiting), but at the time of compilation all components are checked to be valid.

Comment: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/02/25/How-SQL-Server-short-circuits-WHERE-condition-evaluation.aspx